# Loopback 4:How to get Parent data based on combination of querying parent and related model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

Relation: Customer hasMany Orders

```
Customer
id: number
name: string
```

```
Order
id: number
date: number

# assume relation on Customer with "orders" exists.
@belongsTo(Customer)
customerId: number
```

How to query Customers name like '%Kat%' and Order date between(epoch) 1579828913, 1580828913.
I was trying below query, but it is not giving required results.

```
{
  "where": {
    "name": {
        "ilike": "%Kat%"
    }
  },
  "include": [
    {
      "relation": "orders",
      "scope": {
         "where": {
             "date": {
                "between": [1579828913, 1580828913]
             }
          }
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A current limitation of included models is the inability to add scope. See more here where is says filtering by parent model:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html#limitations
You'll have to do it manually, by finding the customers, then the orders.

Answer (score 0):

LoopBack 4 enables custom scope now. And other query clauses should be able to apply with inclusion as well. For example, you have the following instances of mode `Customer` and `Order`:

```
Customer: [
{id: 1, name: 'Luigi'},
{id: 2, name: 'Mario'}
]
Order: [
{id: 1, description: 'Vacuum', customerId: 1},
{id: 2, description: 'Hat', customerId: 1}
]
```

with query:

```
await customerRepo.find({
        where: {
          name: 'Luigi',
        },
        include: [{relation: 'orders', scope: {where: {description: 'Vacuum'}}}],
      });
```

This query would allow you to filter `Customer` with `name="Luigi"` and also filter the related orders with `description='Vacuum'`.

Your query seems correct. LB4 uses the same format for where clause as LB3, reference: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html. The problem *might* have something to do with model definitions.

If you still have problem with querying, feel free to open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next

Comment: my requirement was to get the Parent data (here `Customer`) based on query on both parent and child models, not inclusion of child (related models).